# Corrupted java swing component

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on a Java Swing project,

I have an issue with some component while running projects vs running the interface here's some screen shoot :

[This look when I run only the jFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOPhD.png)

[This is when I run A Frame that lead to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKMj2.png)

[and this when i run the full project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB5VW.png)

I want to know why this look difference and how to resolve it.

I'm Using netbeans 12.2 with jdk 15.0.2 on a windows 64 bit machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Swing by default uses native GUI components. The upside of this is that when done correctly, your Java application will have a Windows style on Windows and a Linux on Linux etc. To get a fixed style, you can set the Java Look And Feel to a LAF that is always available, such as the built-in `METAL` LAF. [This page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) contains much more specifics on Java Look And Feels, how to set them and even how to create your own if you wish.

Comment: thank you so much, @pieter12345 I have changed the look and feel for the first interface and its look good, i want to vote for your response but I have no reputation, so thank you